# How can I color Strings in the strings.xml file using HTML tags?

Tags: java, android

I am creating a PokéDex-like application. I am using a RecyclerViewer with the FastItemAdapter from Mike Penz. I have various variables in my Pokemon class and two of which I'm having trouble with are String type and String weakness.

My goal is to use HTML tags in the strings.xml file in order to add font colors.

In my ModelGenerator class, where I have my entire list of Pokemon, I called the respective string from the strings.xml file.

Pokemon (I am not showing the getters and setters)

```
package com.example.pokedex;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes;

public class Pokemon implements Parcelable {

    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final String type;
    private final String weakness;
    private final int drawableResource;
    private final String description;
    private final String category;
    private final String ability;
    private final String abilityDescription;
    private final String stats;
    private final String height;
    private final String weight;
    private final String gender;
    private Pokemon evolution;

    public Pokemon(int id, String name, String type, String weakness, @DrawableRes int drawableResource,
                   String description, String category, String ability, String abilityDescription,
                   String stats, String height, String weight, String gender) {
        this.id=id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.weakness = weakness;
        this.drawableResource = drawableResource;
        this.description = description;
        this.category = category;
        this.ability = ability;
        this.abilityDescription = abilityDescription;
        this.stats = stats;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    protected Pokemon(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        name = in.readString();
        type = in.readString();
        weakness = in.readString();
        drawableResource = in.readInt();
        description = in.readString();
        category = in.readString();
        ability = in.readString();
        abilityDescription = in.readString();
        stats = in.readString();
        height = in.readString();
        weight = in.readString();
        gender = in.readString();
        evolution = in.readParcelable(Pokemon.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(type);
        dest.writeString(weakness);
        dest.writeInt(drawableResource);
        dest.writeString(description);
        dest.writeString(category);
        dest.writeString(ability);
        dest.writeString(abilityDescription);
        dest.writeString(stats);
        dest.writeString(height);
        dest.writeString(weight);
        dest.writeString(gender);
        dest.writeParcelable(evolution, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<Pokemon> CREATOR = new Creator<Pokemon>() {
        @Override
        public Pokemon createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Pokemon(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Pokemon[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Pokemon[size];
        }
    };
```

strings.xml

```
    <resources>
    <string name="grass_poison"><font color='#53E204'>Grass</font>\u0020<font color='#EB09FC'>Poison</font></string>
<string name="b_i_v_weakness"><font color='#FF0000'>Fire</font>\u0020<font color='#7158FC'>Flying</font>\u0020<font color='#1BE4EB'>Ice</font>\u0020<font color='#E91E63'>Psychic</font></string>
    </resources>
```

ModelGenerator (I'm only showing one pokemon for the sake of simplicity)

```
package com.example.pokedex;

import android.content.Context;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ModelGenerator {

    public static List < Pokemon > getPokemons(Context context) {
        List < Pokemon > pokemons = new ArrayList < > ();

        Pokemon bulbasaur = new Pokemon(1, "Bulbasaur", context.getString(R.string.grass_poison), context.getString(R.string.b_i_v_weakness),
            R.drawable.bulbizarre, context.getString(R.string.bulbizarre_description), "Seed", "Overgrow",
            context.getString(R.string.overgrow_description),
            "HP : 2 \nAttack : 3 \nDefense : 2 \nSpecial Attack : 3 \nSpecial Defense : 3 \nSpeed : 3",
            "62 cm", "7 kg", "♂ | ♀");
        pokemons.add(bulbasaur);
    }
}
```

When I set the type and weakness in their respective TextView they show up but not in any color whatsoever.
What am I missing?

Comment: Hello Donato, welcome to SO! What do you mean by `weakness`? Did you mean something else? I wouldn't store that information in HTML, but in any case, you'd want to read about [SpannableStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) and everything surrounding that.

Comment: weakness is the name of my variable, it's what tells you which element(s) pokémon are weak against (it's a String). I wanted to use the SpannableStringBuilder but I don't know how to apply that to a list in a recyclerview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually wrap the HTML portion in CDATA section something like

```
<string name="grass_poison"><![CDATA[<font color='#53E204'>Grass</font>]]>\u0020<![CDATA[<font color='#EB09FC'>Poison</font>]]></string>
```

And when setting the text use,

```
Html.fromHtml(context.getString(R.string.grass_poison));
```

Comment: I just tried it and for me the string in strings.xml is underlined red. Do I have to implement something?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the error! Anyways, your solution works! Thank you SO much!!